# Anyone have experience using Eigen and GoogleTest together?

Tags: c++, eigen, googletest

So I am writing a math based graphics library.  A lot of the classes use Eigen as the underlying data structure.  For example, my 2 dimensional vector class wraps a Vector2d and adds some functionality specific to my rendering engine.  I have also written a variety of tests using google's testing framework.

With these tests, I have been getting the following error while running tests:

```
Assertion failed: (reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertio
n is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalign
edArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****", file c:\users\***\densestorage.h, line 86
```

I have gone through the documentation specified above and fixed everything I can (I added the macro to override new and delete), am not using stl classes, and have verified that all my functions pass by const reference.  I have a feeling the problem lies in the way the TEST and TEST_F macros are expanded.  Anyone have any ideas what could be going on or how to fix it?

I should also note that classes containing non-aligned types like Vector3d have no problems.  I would like to solve it without turning off the memory alignment, so I can keep things as efficient as possible. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details. I have written a simple test and verified that TEST does not conflict or cause problems with Eigen alignment.

Comment: After working with it a little bit it looks like the problem has to do with using the TEST_F macro and the way it expands fixtures (Best I can figure it probably creates a class that contains the fixture class with out overloading new which Eigen requires for aligned memory).  When I replace TEST_F with the regular TEST macro and put all the setup code in the test itself it runs fine...slightly annoying but it works.

Comment: I just put sample code into an answer (because it is too much to put into a comment). I do not have a problem using TEST_F. Can you tell me how my sample differs from yours?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
namespace {
struct MyClass {
    Eigen::Vector3f m_v3;
    char m_c;
    double m_d;

    MyClass() {}
};

class MyClassTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    virtual void SetUp() {
    }

    virtual void TearDown() {}

    MyClass m_c;
};
}

TEST_F(MyClassTest, test_eigen2)
{
    this->m_c.m_v3[0] = 0.0;
    this->m_c.m_v3[1] = 1.0;
    this->m_c.m_v3[2] = 2.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(float(i), this->m_c.m_v3[i]);
}
```

Comment: Change the Vector3f member to a Vector2d and see if it causes issues.  A Vector3f is not an aligned structure.

Comment: It still works. I am using x64 with Visual Studio 2013 and an up to date gtest. What are you using?

Comment: Hmm...that's exactly what I am using as well.  x64, VS2013 and gtest 1.7.